# How to access the update and options part when using findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mockingoose

I have a service that uses the findByIdAndUpdate (which uses findOneAndUpdate under the hood), which I need to test.

The problem is that as far as I can tell, the `finderMock` function that I pass to the `toReturn` method get called with just the query, which contains the `id` but neither the `options` nor the `update` objects.

However, to properly test my service's method, I need access to those, since I need to check that the options are correct and that the request is actually trying to update what it should.
Looking at the `query` object and `query.getQuery()`, I don't see anyway to access those objects.

Is there any way to access them ? If not, is there any way to properly test the findAndUpdate type methods ?

Comment: Could you provide a short code sample illustrating your usecase?

Comment: I already got an answer from the author that it's not supported, and since he immediately closed my issue without labeling it as feature request, I gather that he has no intention of adding the support. I found myself replacing the library with my own mocking utility.